# PHP > SOAP created Attributes in header "The Correct way"

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am facing an issue with SOAP Header in PHP

My code should generate something like this

```
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ns1:RequestHeader xmlns:ns1="xxxxxxx">
        <ns1:auth xmlns:ns1="yyyy">
           <ns1:user>xxx</ns1:user>
           <ns1:pass>false</ns1:pass>
       </ns1:auth>
    </ns1:RequestHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
```

The issue, I can't figure out how to do it correctly and I found many tricks to do it but most of them will force me either to change how I send the main XML or change my entire code.

My current code print the following

```
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ns1:RequestHeader>
        <ns1:auth>
           <ns1:user>xxx</ns1:user>
           <ns1:pass>false</ns1:pass>
       </ns1:auth>
    </ns1:RequestHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
```

and my code is

```
$Auth = new stdClass();
$Auth->auth->user = "user";
$Auth->auth->pass = "pass";     

$header = new SoapHeader(true,'RequestHeader',$Auth,false); 

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

What do you think about this, how can I add Attributes correctrly to `RequestHeader`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for that,

```
$header_part = '
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>'."USERNAME".'</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>'."PASSWORD".'</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
';
$soap_var_header = new SoapVar( $header_part, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null );
$soap_header = new SoapHeader( 'http://your-target-service.com', 'wsse', $soap_var_header );
$soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($soap_header);
```

you need to send this with the original soap request.